# Invertible least common multiple matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-common-multiple

I am trying to prove that the matrix $(lcm (i,j))_{1\le i, j \le n}$ is invertible. I know the result for calculating the determinant of this kind of lcm matrix on factor-closed set which deduces this conclusion, but I am looking for some simpler approach. Can you give me some ideas?